# Reactjs - can't set a background image on Bootstrap's Jumbotron

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

The image does not appear and I'm not sure if it's something with the syntax or the path to the image is wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Jumbotron, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


class Jumbo extends Component {
  render() {
    function myFunction() {
      console.log('test');
    }

    return (
      <Jumbotron style={styles.container}>
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
        <p>In a town like Twin Peaks no one is innocent</p>
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          onClick={myFunction}
        >
          Learn more
        </Button>
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
        >
          <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
        </Button>
      </Jumbotron>
    );
  }
}

const bgImage = '../images/twin.jpg';

const styles = {
    container: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${bgImage})`
  }
};
export default Jumbo;
```

The 'Jumbo' component is in 'Components' directory. The 'twin.jpg' is in the 'images' directory. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a path issue -- the react code looks correct. I'm not sure how your project is set up, but usually image assets will go into your `public` directory. Probably `public/images`. Then you would access them from your web server's root directory, the path will probably be:

`url(/images/twin.jpg)`

First try putting the images in the public folder and then try to access them directly through the browser URL.

Comment: That's it. I didn't know that it should be in public. Now you pointed it out, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should you webpack to build project then when you import image, you will have that image www or public folder.